# Visual Studio Core not opening webapi in debug mode or `dotnet run`

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

We use Visual Studio Code to develop dotnet core webapis. Visual Studio Code has all of a sudden stopped opening the web apis in the browser when we use the Debug mode. Or, when using `dotnet run`. As a result, I don't know what URL and port has been assigned to the web application.

What's strange is that there are no errors during the build. And, the web application is written to NLog, so it is obviously running. It's just that it is not automatically opening in the browser, and the VSCode terminal is not returning the URL in the stdout.

Below is the `launch.json` file from the `.vscode` folder:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
            // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
            // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/api-timesheets/bin/Debug/net6.0/api-timesheets.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/api-timesheets",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```